# How to make a raw input a number?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raw-input

I wanted to make a simple program on my raspberry pi that will let a LED flash as many times as the number you type in. My program is working, but is a bit repetitive:

```
times = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
if times == '1':
    times = 1
elif times == '2':
    times = 2
elif times == '3':
    times = 3
elif times == '4':
    times = 4
elif times == '5':
    times = 5
```

This would take a lot of programming to handle a larger inputs like 145.

Does anybody know a smarter and faster way of doing it?

PS: Code is finished;

```
   # I know i need to import GPIO and stuff, this is just an example.
import time
while True:
    try:
        times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter a number!"
print 'Ok, there you go:'
while times > -1: 
    if times > 0:
        print 'hi'
        times = times-1
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    elif times == 0:
        print 'That was it.'
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'Prepare to stop.'
        time.sleep(3)
        print '3'
        time.sleep(1)
        print '2'
        time.sleep(1)
        print '1'
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'BYE'
        break
```

Thank you.

Comment: times = int(raw_input())

Comment: `times = int(float(raw_input('Enter a number: ')))`

Comment: @iluengo, ...why do the double-cast? If you're going to allow it to be a float, might as well cast it there directly rather than implicitly rounding, and if you're not, better to throw an error than silently corrupt data if you get bad input.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I didnt know about the duplicate thingystuff, I guess i had to look around a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
```

If someone enters in something other than an integer, it will throw an exception. If that's not what you want, you could catch the exception and handle it yourself, like this:

```
try:
    times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
except ValueError:
    print "An integer is required."
```

If you want to keep asking for input until someone enters a valid input, put the above in a while loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "An integer is required."
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your input in [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) depending on the data type you are expecting.

```
times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
print type(times)
```

Outputs:

```
Enter a number:  10
<type 'int'>
```

If a user inputs something other than a number, it will throw a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) (for example, inputing `asdf` results in:)

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the input as an integer and catch the exception if it isn't:

```
try:
    times = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
    # do something with the int
except ValueError:
    # not an int
    print 'Not an integer'
```